# process started by python's subprocess doesn't exist

Tags: python, windows, subprocess

I run a 'mstsc' program in win7 using  python's subprocess:

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> p=subprocess.Popen('mstsc')
>>> p.pid
8884
```

However, the '8884' process doesn't exist when I check Windows' process moniter, and another 'mstsc' does exist. So I wonder if the 'mstsc' create another subprocess when calling subprocess. Please help?

Answer (score 6):

Well i m still a newbie on python, but still you can go through this.

The Popen class uses CreateProcess function in windows to execute the child program.
CreateProcess function Creates a new process and its primary thread. This new process runs in the security context of the calling process.

Internally it use the CreateProcessAsUser or CreateProcessWithLogonW functions to run the new process in the security context of the user.

Which as per my understanding would give a different pid to actual executing suprocess.Popen().

Comment: i have tested by starting a 'notepad' using 'subprocess.Popen('notepad')', which returns the same pid as shown in process moniter.

Comment: I have fixed it. the reason for this problem is that the version of python is 32bit while my host is a 64bit. after i upgraded the python, two pids are the same.